# Build-Bot queue individual fluctuate rapidly but overall-sum locks at 601

Tags: factorio

I am building a big base. Unfortunately the Build-Queue fluctuates for no reason.

I am expecting that the amount of buildungs left decreases but it does decrease and increase rapidly.

Do anyone know why the fluctuation? Maybe a technical reason? The overall-queue locks at 601 but the items and item-amounts are changing.

[image]

Comment: I don't know how we're supposed to answer this without seeing your base

Answer (score 5):

**There is no “queue”. What you are seeing is a list of alerts only.**

In order to ensure consistent performance, Factorio does not reevaluate the entire world's possible construction requests all at once. Instead, it checks one build ghost at a time, and checks whether an item and bot are available. If they are, the task is assigned to the bot; if not, an alert is generated. There is a limit of at most one alert generation per tick, and they last for 10 seconds = 600 ticks, so can only ever be about 600 construction alerts visible at once.

The lifetime of alerts has nothing to do with how bots are dispatched. There is no harm to your bots' performance from this display fluctuation.

---

If you want the alerts to be processed faster than the default 1 per tick, thus allowing more alerts to be displayed, you could change the internal setting like so:

```
/c game.player.force.max_failed_attempts_per_tick_per_construction_queue = 2
```

to get 1200 alerts, or a higher number for more.

Note that this will count as a "cheat" and disable achievements. I found it in [this Factorio forum thread](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?t=57921).

Comment: You mean the warning will be disappear after 10 seconds. This means if nothing is built, all warnings will disappear after 10 seconds. I can not confirm this behaviour.

Comment: @PeterRader No, the game is constantly rechecking whether orders can be satisfied and generating alerts as long as there are any that can't. The 10 seconds is just how long any individual alert lasts — for example, if you have a single rocket silo to be built, it will show up in the alert list for 10 seconds and then be replaced by other things, and then come back.

Comment: (That example might not be exactly correct; it's just how I understand things will work, not something I have observed exactly.)

Comment: I mean when the warnings are seamlessly replaced I should not see a fluctuation. Also I do not care about how bots are dispatched. I care about the warnings and 20seconds*60 is 1200 what might solve the initial problem because 1200 > 600. This means by increasing the lifetime of warnings will get rid of the fluctuation.

Comment: @PeterRader I've added a command which will increase the speed of alert generation and I've verified in-game that it will get you to 1200 alerts.